# Cannot access OneDrive items through the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm having an issue while trying to access my OneDrive items through the Graph API.

Endpoint: `/v1.0/me/drive/items/{myItemID}/workbook/worksheets`

Raw request:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/FF********/workbook/worksheets HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer ******************
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: **********
```

Raw response:

```http
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 88e690c8-590e-40f9-9f01-46d22294835b
client-request-id: 88e690c8-590e-40f9-9f01-46d22294835b
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_17","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
Duration: 179.4482
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 09:40:39 GMT
Content-Length: 236

{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "General Exception While Processing",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "88e690c8-590e-40f9-9f01-46d22294835b",
      "date": "2017-10-06T09:40:40"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to open this file in Excel without a problem?

Comment: Yes I am. I also tried with a new file and still got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue was recently discovered that forced a temporary disabling of `/workbook` for OneDrive Consumer. The fix has been deployed, but due to the nature of the issue it will be reactivated slowly. You should hopefully see it start working for various accounts over the next few weeks.